# Check html cell for a button

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to check if a cell in an html table contains a button?  This cell would only contain a button, or nothing.

Currently, I am using

```
if (table.rows[1].cells[0].value === undefined) {
```

however, this will detect no button when there actually is one.

Comment: cells don't have values, they have innerHTML

Comment: Can you please edit your question to provide an example of the table that you are wanting to test?

Comment: Like @Taplar said, a cell doesn't have a value, but children. Can you try with ..cells[0].children[0] ?

Comment: @BertMaurau if the cell is a button or empty, it might be better to do `cells[0].children.length`, no?  Avoid the possible out of bounds exception.

Comment: @Taplar Yes, correct indeed!

Comment: @BertMaurau .children[0] works perfectly! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `table.rows[1].cells[0].children[0].nodeName` is equal to `"BUTTON"` to see if the table's second row's first cell's first child is a button.

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>s</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button>Button</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  
  if (table.rows[1].cells[0].children[0] && table.rows[1].cells[0].children[0].nodeName == "BUTTON") {
    console.log("Table row 2 cell 1 contains a button element");
  } else {
    console.log("Table row 2 cell 1 does not contain a button element");
  }
  if (table.rows[0].cells[0].children[0] && table.rows[0].cells[0].children[0].nodeName == "BUTTON") {
    console.log("Table row 1 cell 1 contains a button element");
  } else {
    console.log("Table row 1 cell 1 does not contain a button element");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `firstElementChild` and `lastElementChild` to do that like so:

```
var cell = table.rows[1].cells[0];
if(cell.firstElementChild                                               // if this cell has a child
   && cell.firstElementChild === cell.lastElementChild                  // if that child is the only child
   && cell.firstElementChild.tagName.toLowerCase() === "button") {      // if that child is a button
    // ok
}
```

**Note:** This will skip non-element children like textnodes. It only checks for elements.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do:

```
if (document.querySelector('td button')) 
  console.log('Yes, there is a button in a table cell!');
```

Comment: You are missing the end bracket for the `if` statement. It should be: `if (document.querySelector('td button') )`

Comment: @hev: yes, of course! Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed it now.

Comment: @carso10m No problem.